# How can I send a variable from a controller to a behaviour? cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have created a behaviour for my Tables which sets in the beforeSave() method two basic variables of a table: created_by and created_on(same for modified and deleted).

- The created_on column of the table stores the time at which the object in that class has been created.
- The created_by column currently stores a string 'unkown', but my intention is to store the username of the active user from the current session.

I currently use the active_user in my controllers, setting it from the beforeFilter() method of AppController. How can I send active_user->username from my controller to the behaviour? Is there a possible way? Or an alternative method of sending a string to the behaviour?

Comment: Use sessions to store to active username in your tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that cake has a builtin behavior to save the `created` and `modified` date. All you have to do enable it in the Table. (see the manual [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/timestamp.html))

```
 $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
```

To save the even the user I use a plugin which set a global variable in the controller (you can do it in your AppController)

```
$authUser = $controller->Auth->user();
Configure::write('GlobalAuth', $authUser);
```

and in the behavior

```
$user_id = Configure::read('GlobalAuth.id');
```

But sincerely I don't know if this is the best method.

the plugin I use is this, for your information

https://github.com/cakemanager/cakephp-utils

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly and i am sending only the $active_user->username to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [muffin/footprint](https://github.com/usemuffin/footprint) plugin and customize which data you want to save in beforeSave.